# $http.get() error : $http.get is not a function

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-services

I'm creating a dataService to handle all http connections, here's my code for that:

```
(function(){
angular.module('theswapp')
       .factory('dataService',['$http','$q',function($q, $http){

        function getTeamCheckInData(){
            return $http.get('assets/js/data.json');
        }

        return {
            getTeamCheckInData : getTeamCheckInData
        };

  }]);
})();
```

After injecting it in my controller and envoking it i'm getting a error at **return $http.get('assets/js/data.json');** .Error says *$http.get is not a function*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The orders of the parameters in the factory  is wrong , it should be

```
angular.module('theswapp')
       .factory('dataService',['$http','$q',function($http,$q ){
```